# Combining Array with Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have the following arrays of arrays w a little overlapping of elements:

```
arr1 = [[a,b], [c,d], [e,f], [g, h]]
arr2 = [[a, 1, 2, 3], [c, 4, 5, 6], [e, 7, 8, 9], [g, 10, 11, 12]]
```

How can I get to

```
arr1 = [[a, b, 1, 2, 3], [c, d, 4, 5, 6], [e, f, 7, 8, 9], [g, h, 10, 11, 12]]
```

I have tried looping this and using splice, split, concat but am having some issue with the logic. Thanks in advance.

Here is an idea of where I'm at (this has been modified a little from the last version that was kind of close to working):

```
    for(var x = 0; x <arr2.length; x++){

         arr1[x] = arr2[x][0].split(" ");

      //   arr1 = arr1[x].concat(2,0,arr2[x+1]); 
    }
```

Comment: Are first elements in the array always the same?

Comment: Yes - I want to basically not include the first element of arr2 in the final version of arr1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ES5, you can now use the forEach method:

```
arr2.forEach(function(item, index) {
   arr1[index] = arr1[index].concat(item.splice(1));
});
```

Alternatively, you could use the more traditional for loop:

```
for(var i=0, len=arr2.length; i<len; i+=1) {
    arr1[i] = arr1[i].concat(arr2[i].splice(1));
}
```

(in both, the `splice(1)` is because it appears you only want to concatenate the elements after the first item)

Comment: Nice - is there a way to do this w a standard for loop?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly , the code maybe like this :

```
arr1 = [[a,b], [c,d], [e,f], [g, h]]
arr2 = [[a, 1, 2, 3], [c, 4, 5, 6], [e, 7, 8, 9], [g, 10, 11, 12]]


function combin(head, source) {
    var result = [];
    head.map(function (h) {               // iterate arr1 elements
        source.map(function (s) {              // iterate arr2 elements
            if(h[0] == s[0]){
                s.shift();                     // remove the first element
                result.push(h.concat(s));      // concat the array
            }
        });
    });

    return result;
}
console.log(combin(arr1, arr2));
```

tip:

- the shift() will change the origin array
- the concat() won't change the origin array , just return a new array for result